# How do I stop a localScroll event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have `localScroll` initialised with the following settings:

```
// Local scroll settings 
$.localScroll({
  event:'click',
  axis:'y',
  duration:500,
  offset:-30,
  hash:true,
  stop:true
});
```

That's fine as an all-purpose setup but I also have some links with hrefs that match the above for which I *don't* want `localScroll` to fire. Here's an excerpt:

```
<ul class="line tabs">
  <li class="unit"><a href="#foo" class="active">Foo</a></li>
```

I have a click event handler that runs a custom function on the 4 links of this type:

```
$('.home .tabs a').click(activate_tab);
```

The `activate_tab` function includes:

```
return false;
```

but I've realised that `localScroll` is firing and overriding that.

How can I stop localScroll from firing on these specific click events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other events bound to the click on those links, you can do

```
$('.home .tabs a').unbind('click').click(activate_tab);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I've accepted the answer. Can't vote it up yet as I don't have enough rep as a noob.

Comment: Thanks to you! Good luck with your site.